# JPA ids auto_increment generation

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

Am using JPA into my application and then the when insert different objects the database use sequential ids.

For Example:

If i have table member and table user , when inserting object of type user will take id = 1 then add object into table member will take id = 2 .

The problem is : i imported  a .sql file into the database.

Then when i insert  a new record from my application it cause an exception because it use ids already added.

How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: What is the @GenerationValue strategy used for the ID of your domain objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the start value for `AUTO_INCREMENT` as

```
ALTER TABLE tbl AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

**See also:**

- [3.6.9. Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)